# Synchronous notifications with notify-send and xfce4-notifyd?

Tags: notifications, xfce

I intend to send synchronous volume notifications in arch(changing volume and showing the progress bar) and was wondering if I can do this with plain `notify-send` and `xfce4-notifyd`(eg. a hint or something).

**EDIT1:** More precisely I want new volume notifications to replace old ones so that it emulates a volume meter and it doesn't flood my screen.

If not, is this possible with `notify-osd` or do I need to actually use libnotify?

Answer (score 1):

Or try zenity. You can do all kinds of fun things with notifications, including progress bars (although they use a regular popup window).

Comment: I was actually referring to notifications as in notification-dameon or notify-osd. I'm not looking to use dialogs.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I thought Zenity did those, but now I try it I see my scripts used zenity for the indicator icons, and notify-send for the pop-up notifications.